# unable to access date value after lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
Main Collection
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5ea1a07bfd7e4965408a5171"),
    "data": [],
    "history_id": ObjectID("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
    "sender_id": ObjectID("5e4e74eb380054797d9db623"),
    "text": "Hi tester",
    "date": 1587650683434
}

History collection
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5ea1afd4f4151402efd234e3"),
    "user_id": [
        "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764"
    ],
    "dialog_id": ObjectID("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
    "date": 1587549034211,
    "__v": 1
}

const messages = await MainModal.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'history',
          localField: 'history_id',
          foreignField: 'history_id',
          as: 'History'
        }
      },

      { $unwind: '$History' },

      { "$match" : { date: {$gt: "History.date" } } }, // this is not working
])
```

I am getting value inside $history but enable to fetch matched record. I don't know why i read somewhere $gt does work on number my date is number too

when i set string instead "History.date" it does work but after putting this doesnot work

Basically my idea is not to display those value whose `date` are `$lt` from history collection and where user not in `5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the query language with aggregation operators.  In order to use `$match` to compare two fields from the same document, you will need to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) along with aggregation operators.

For that final match stage, use

```
{ "$match":{ "$expr":{ "$gt":[ "$date", "$History.date" ] } } }
```

**Edit**

Adding an additional comparison between other fields would need to use `$and` or `$or`, like:

```
{ "$match":{ 
       "$expr":{ 
             "$and":[
                   {"$gt":[ "$date", "$History.date" ] },
                   {"$not": {"$eq":[ "$sender_id", "$History.user_id" ]}}
             ]
        } 
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4g_7fzzeOVm)

Comment: Awesome I was using express but it was saying two parameters is require in $gt any way that's fine one more help in it if I wanted to add one more condition $in will this be inside $expr please update your answer if possible

Comment: Basically my idea is not to display those value whose date are $lt from history collection and where user not in 5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764

Comment: Is `5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764` being passed in with the query, or is it coming from the document?

Comment: I am eager to understand both case you can see my both collection sender_id MainCollection and user_id historyCollection how easy I can use those combination.

Comment: I do not want to display data those requested is store in history collection

Comment: I tried this way { "$match": { "$expr":{ "$gt":[ "$date", "$History.date" ] } }, "$sender_id" :{ $nin: [selfID] } },

Comment: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Comment: So you want to match (MainCollection.date > HistoryCollection.date) && (MainCollection.sender_id != HistoryCollection.user_id)?

Comment: Thanks for best your support I read the document and tried myself 

{ "$match": {
             "$expr": { "$and": [
                  { "$gt":[ "$date", "$History.date" ] },
                  { "$not": { "$in": ["5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764", ["$History.user_id"]] }}
              ] } 
          }
      },

Comment: It should return nothing check this @joe

Comment: In your example, `$History.user_id` is already an array, so `$in: [ "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",[ $History.user_id"]]}` is testing against `[ ["5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764"] ]`, which is an array whose only element is an array.  Since `"5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764"` and `["5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764"]` are different data types, these don't match.